# How to set a knockout property with a MVC model view property in a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

i have the next scenario:

Im working with knockout (ver 2.1.0) and ASP MVC.NET, so in one specific point my controller calls a new view. This view renders a partial view with the next call:

```
<div id="productSeriesNonSocks">
    @{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/SalesOrderManagement/GetAvailableProductSeriesNonSocks.cshtml", Model);
     }
</div>
```

The controller called the view with a viewModel (Model) with a few properties, so the above call sends the whole model to the partial view.

In the partial view I can access the model properties with a simple sentence like this:

```
Available season type: @Model.SeasonType
```

The problem starts here... the partial view has it own knockout model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //activates KO
    ko.applyBindings(productSeriesNonSocksModel);
    GetDataFromModels();
});

var productSeriesNonSocksModel = {
    AvailableProductSeriesNonSocks: ko.observableArray([]),
    selectedProdSeries: ko.observable(),
    seasonType: ko.observable()
};

function GetDataFromModels() {
    $.get('/SalesOrderManagement/GetAvailableProductSeriesNonSocks', { seasonType: this.seasonType() }, function (data) {
        productSeriesNonSocksModel.AvailableProductSeriesNonSocks(data.AvailableProductSeriesNonSocks);
    });
}

</script>
```

the GetDataFromModels() function should call a method in the controller with the seasonType as a parameter in order to retrieve the proper array and put it on the AvailableProductSeriesNonSocks array. The problem here is that I don't know how to pass the value from a property model (in this case @Model.SeasonType) to the knockout model to call the function in the controller (productSeriesNonSocksModel.seasonType).

I tried to pass the value with:

```
seasonType: ko.observable(@Model.SeasonType)
```

or

```
seasonType: @Model.SeasonType
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea to pass a model property value to the knockout property value in order to make the call with the $.get(...)?

To clarify, I can't just ask the value because that value (SeasonType) was choosen by the user in the previous view.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the rendered html, what does @Model.SeasonType show?

Comment: The current value Tyrsius, for example: "InSeason", so in the model is passed properly to partial view.

Comment: ... and that value is what i need to make the call to be process for the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use razor in script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var seasonType = @Model.SeasonType;
    // do something with season type
</script>
```

It might also make sense to avoid the additional request. You could put the data from "/SalesOrderManagement/GetAvailableProductSeriesNonSocks" in the model or the ViewBag and render that as JavaScript Object.

Comment: Thanks for answer! but i have get an error related to JScript about the non-definition for the value that SeasonType has. The same happens with the other two options.

Comment: It works if you use "", so the statement is: var seasonType = "@Model.SeasonType"; and it can be used in the $.get parameter. Thank you!!